# How to use Python to read one column from Excel file?

Tags: python, excel

I want to read the data in one column in excel, here is my code:

```
import xlrd

file_location = "location/file_name.xlsx"

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)

sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('sheet')

x = []

for cell in sheet.col[9]:

    if isinstance(cell, float):

        x.append(cell)

print(x)
```

It is wrong because there is no method in sheet called col[col.num], but I just want to extract the data from column 8 (column H), what can I do?

Comment: sorry , column 8, not 9

Comment: Edit your original question to edit any mistakes you found. You can edit your question as many times as you want.

Answer (score 14):

If you're not locked with xlrd I would probably have used pandas instead which is pretty good when working with data from anywhere:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.ExcelFile('location/test.xlsx').parse('Sheet1') #you could add index_col=0 if there's an index
x=[]
x.append(df['name_of_col'])
```

You could then just write the new extracted columns to a new excel file with pandas `df.to_excel()`

Answer (score 5):

You can get the values of the 8th column like this:

```
for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
    x.append(sheet.cell(rownum, 7))
```

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way to get all the values in a column using `xlrd` is the `col_values()` worksheet method:

```
x = []
for value in sheet.col_values(8):
    if isinstance(value, float):
        x.append(value)
```

(Note that if you want column H, you should use 7, because the indices start at 0.)

Incidentally, you *can* use `col()` to get the cell *objects* in a column:

```
x = []
for cell in sheet.col(8):
    if isinstance(cell.value, float):
        x.append(cell.value)
```

The best place to find this stuff is the official [tutorial](http://www.simplistix.co.uk/presentations/python-excel.pdf) (which serves as a decent reference for `xlrd`, `xlwt`, and `xlutils`). You could of course also check out the [documentation](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966) and the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to do it as:

```
import openpyxl
fname = 'file.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fname)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('sheet-name')
for rowOfCellObjects in sheet['C5':'C7']:
  for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
    print(cellObj.coordinate, cellObj.value)
```

> Result:
>  C5 70.82
>  C6 84.82
>  C7 96.82

Note: **fname** refers to excel file, **get_sheet_by_name('sheet-name')** refers to desired sheet and in **sheet['C5':'C7']** ranges are mentioned for columns.

Check out the [link](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/) for more detail. Code segment taken from here too.

Answer (score 0):

XLRD is good, but for this case you might find Pandas good because it has routines to select columns by using an operator '[ ]'

**Complete Working code for your context would be**

```
import pandas as pd
file_location = "file_name.xlsx"
sheet = pd.read_excel(file_location)
print(sheet['Sl'])
```

Output 1 - For column 'Sl'

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: Sl, dtype: int64
```

Output 2 - For column 'Name'

```
print(sheet['Name'])
0      John
1      Mark
2    Albert
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Reference: file_name.xlsx data

```
Sl  Name
1   John
2   Mark
3   Albert
```

Comment: Incomplete, please tell us what is `x`?

Comment: @not2qubit Thanks for pointing this error.  Had rewritten from my codebase to simplify, but missed to use the same object names.  x here should have been sheet.  sheet is the pandas object am using.  Will fix this and update my answer.  Thanks!